# Read iDevice information via USB

Tags: iphone, dll

My goal is to be able to take in device information when an iphone is plugged into my windows computer. I want to be able to read things like model, serial, storage, etc.

I believe Apple has a dll that does exactly this, however, I cannot find any documentation on how to use it. In my file system it is called AppleMobileDeviceSupport_main.dll

I can find information that tells me the Apple Mobile Device Support is responsible for doing exactly what I want (reading the device when attached via cable), but nothing gets technical.

The screenshot here is from an app called 3utools which does what I exactly what I need to do.
[device information here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFvuJ.png)

I'm not necessarily looking to be spoon fed. Just something to read so I can understand how to go about the solution.

Thanks in advace.

Edit like 3 months later:
I found a git repo that does what I want. It is written in C and might take some time to understand. Look through the tools implementation in the repo if you need to understand it better.
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can write an iOS Mono/Xamarain app with Visual Studio. You could theoretically, use their built-in APIs, and do a

`Console.WriteLine(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString());`

I'm sure you need a Mac though for remote sessions. I've seen people use third party software to get debug logs from Windows tethering iOS device, so there could be another way. I think it's called iTools?

Comment: i will look into it for sure, thanks